# SSL connection encryption negotiation

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

I've installed a .Net-based website on multiple virtual machines (Windows 2012 R2), using the same version of the same installer on both.  Part of this installation includes generation of a self-signed ssl certificate.  When accessing the two websites over https, one is indicating "secure connection failed" when using Firefox, however the other server/website works fine.  Both load in IE fine.

When looking at the page properties (from IE), the failing site indicates a connection of "TLS 1.0, AES with 128 bit encryption (High); RSA with 2048 bit exchange", while the successful one indicates "TLS 1.2, AES with 256 bit encryption (High); ECDH_P256 with 256 bit exchange".

What server settings should I be looking at to determine the difference between the two?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2, .Net 4.5, IIS 8.5

Comment: TLS 1.0 is the problem.

Comment: My googling has led me to the registry settings at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\", where I can presumably disable TLS 1.0.  However, those settings appear identical between the working and failing servers.  Is this the correct location to make TLS changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this down to an incompatibility between the self-signed certificate, which was using SHA512, and TLS.  Changing the certificate to use SHA256 resolved the issue.  The reason for the failure on one VM vs another was a registry setting, which dictated whether or not to support SHA512.  The succeeding machine supported 512, the failing one did not.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/silvana/2014/03/14/schannel-errors-on-scom-agent/